# Paperclip attachment column in database is empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have installed paperclip and imagemagick,and implemented the code to my model and view file.
I have a database column named 'picture' and it is empty no matter if i uploaded a picture or not. the picture acctually exists in the`/public/system/decks/pictures/000/000/019/medium` folder. i can see all of the uploaded pictures there, but i can't show them cause the database is empty.

My model:

```
class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :picture

  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  attr_accessor :picture_file_name
  attr_accessor :picture_content_type
  attr_accessor :picture_file_size
  attr_accessor :picture_updated_at
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for @deck,:url => decks_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :slika %>
```

My migration:

```
class AddAttachmentPictureToDecks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :decks, :picture, :attachment
  end
end
```

So i get the picture in that folder that i have mentioned before but the `picture` column in my decks table is empty. I can't get the picture with `<%= image_tag @deck.picture.url(:medium) %>`, cause my `@deck.picture.url` holds a `/pictures/original/missing.png`, my `@deck.picture.path` and my `@deck.picture.picture_file_name` also shows nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `<%= f.file_field :slika %>` be `<%= f.file_field :picture %>` instead?

Comment: Also: If you have these fields in the database, you don't have to define accessors for them.

Comment: it is picture, iwas translating from my mother language and i guess i missed that on. i only have a picture column in my table but none of the accessors are in there

Comment: I'm not familiar with the new Paperclip migration helpers, but the doc says it should look like this: `add_attachment :decks, :picture` (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/#quick-start)

Comment: tried that also put and ran a migration again and nothing happened

Comment: Did you roll back beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end it looks like i mixed the old syntax and the new one and i couldn't get the fields right in the database. and it looks like the attr_accessors are unneccessary